# Google Map Zoom to Boundaries

Tags: javascript, maps

I've tried multiple code examples and other Stack Overflow threads and had no luck.

I want to set the map to the boundaries of the locations within the query. I have tried multiple examples with no success.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
                    foreach($store_posts as $store):
                    $post = $store->ID;
                    setup_postdata($post);

                    $location = get_field('address');
                    $map_lat = $location['google_map']['lat'];
                    $map_lang = $location['google_map']['lng'];
                    $address = $location['google_map']['address'];

                    $wha_location = array();
                    $latitude = $map_lat;
                    $longitude = $map_lang;

                    if(!empty($latitude) && !empty($longitude) && $latitude != 'NEEDS_GEOCODE' && $longitude != 'NEEDS_GEOCODE'){
                        $wha_location['title'] = get_the_title();
                        $wha_location['address'] = $address;
                        // $wha_location['image'] = get_field('images')[0]['url'];
                        $wha_location['latitude'] = $latitude;
                        $wha_location['longitude'] = $longitude;
                        $wha_location['url'] = get_the_permalink();
                        $map_data[] = $wha_location;
                    }
                ?>
                    <?php // vd(get_field('wha_locatione_map')); ?>
                    <?php // the_title(); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <div id="map-search-results" class="block__properties">
                <div id="map" style="height: 800px; width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>

            <?php // vd($map_data); ?>

            <script>
                function initMap() {
                    var data = <?php echo json_encode($map_data); ?>;

                    <?php if(!empty($_REQUEST['latitude']) && !empty($_REQUEST['longitude']) && !isset($_REQUEST['search_by']) && in_array($_REQUEST['search_by'], $states)): ?>
                        var mapOptions = {zoom: 10, center: {lat: parseFloat(<?php echo $_REQUEST['latitude']; ?>), lng: parseFloat(<?php echo $_REQUEST['longitude']; ?>) }};
                    <?php elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['latitude']) && !empty($_REQUEST['longitude']) && isset($_REQUEST['search_by']) && in_array($_REQUEST['search_by'], $states)): ?>
                        var mapOptions = {zoom: 7, center: {lat: parseFloat(<?php echo $_REQUEST['latitude']; ?>), lng: parseFloat(<?php echo $_REQUEST['longitude']; ?>) }};
                    <?php else: ?>
                        var mapOptions = {zoom: 5, center: {lat: -23.9112851, lng: 133.7608473}};
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                    data.map(function (item, index) {
                    var position = {lat: parseFloat(item.latitude), lng: parseFloat(item.longitude)};
                    var contentString = '<div class="col-12">'+
                        '<div class="card ml-0 mr-0">'+
                        // '<div class="search__results--thumbnail-map">'+
                        // '<img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="'+ item.image +'">'+
                        // '</div>'+
                        '<div class="card-body search__results--card-body">'+
                        '<p class="card-title font-color-br-dark-blue text-truncate-two-line">'+ item.title +'</p>'+
                        '<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted text-truncate-two-line">'+ item.address +'</small></p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="card-footer search__results--card-footer">'+
                        '<ul class="list-inline search__results--list-inline">'+
                        '<li class="list-inline-item">'+
                    '<a href="'+ item.url +'" target="_blank">'+
                        '<i class="fas fa-eye search__results--view"></i> <span class="search__results--action-text">View</span>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '</li>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                    // var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    //   content: contentString,
                    //   maxWidth: 300
                    // });
                    var icon = {
                        // url: "<?php echo esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()); ?>/img/noun-map-pin-665681 (1).png", 
                        // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25), // scaled size
                        // origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                        // anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                    };
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, map: map, icon: icon});

                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString,
                        maxWidth: 300
                        });
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                    });
                }
            </script>




        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I understand I need to remove some of the code around "mapOptions", but I am trying to do this automatically without having to have some options for a user to administer it.